# Updating Azure Application via Microsoft Graph SDK

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am using the Microsoft Graph SDK (https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) in my .NET Core 3.1 project logged in to my Service Principal. I can retrieve the Azure Application's Web Reply URLs:

```
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var rootItem = await graphClient.Applications.Request().GetAsync();
Microsoft.Graph.Application app = new Microsoft.Graph.Application();
            foreach (var item in rootItem)
            {
                if (item.DisplayName.Equals("MyApp"))
                {
                    app = item;
                }
            }
```

I am able to retrieve the actual Application object just fine. My question is, how do I update `app.Web.RedirectUris` through the SDK? I am able to do so via the Azure CLI with `az ad app update --id <my_app_id> --reply-urls <url_1> <url_2>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get an `Microsoft.Graph.IApplicationRequestBuilder` for the specific `Application` and then call `UpdateAsync()` method.

```
var rootItem = await client.Applications.Request().GetAsync();
Microsoft.Graph.Application app = new Microsoft.Graph.Application();
foreach (var item in rootItem)
{
    if (item.DisplayName.Equals("MyApp"))
    {
        app = item;
        app.Web.RedirectUris = new List<string> { "uri1", "uri2" };
        await client.Applications[app.Id].Request().UpdateAsync(app);
    }
}
```

Comment: If we Update "RedirectUris" to 2 new uris, will it going to replace or Add ?

Comment: @Snigdha Good point. It will replace old collection with a new one.